# Adding document in snapshotChanges adds 2 documents

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

So I am trying to add a document if a query returns 0 documents. And I have gotten it to create the new document but for some reason it creates 2? Is there a way for me to limit it to creating only one?

Here is the method

```
this.currentMonth = this.monthCollection.snapshotChanges().map(snapshot => {
  if (snapshot.length <= 0) {
    this.createNewMonth(); <---- THIS GETS CALLED TWICE
  }
  return snapshot.map(doc => {
    const data = doc.payload.doc.data();
    data.id = doc.payload.doc.id;
    this.currentMonthId = doc.payload.doc.id;
    this.currentMonthTotalSpent = doc.payload.doc.data().totalSpent;

    this.expenseCollection = this.monthCollection.doc(doc.payload.doc.id).collection('expenses');
    this.expenses = this.expenseCollection.snapshotChanges().map(snapshot => {
      return snapshot.map(doc => {
        const data = doc.payload.doc.data();
        data.id = doc.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    });
    return data;
  });
});
```

EDIT: So a bit more detail when the app opens I need to check firestore for a month object that has an end timestamp that is greater than the current time. If that is not the case (which means its a new month) I need to create a new month. I placed the method that creates the new month below for reference. The problem I am having is that 2 documents are created and I need just one.

```
  createNewMonth() {
    let date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
    let firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
    let lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);

    let newMonth = {
      categories: [],
      endTimestamp: moment(lastDay).unix(),
      name: this.getMonthNameFromTimestamp(moment().unix()),
      startTimestamp: moment(firstDay).unix(),
      totalSpent: 0
    }
    this.monthCollection.add(newMonth);
  }
```

EDIT 2: Just for reference here is the `monthCollection`

```
this.monthCollection = this.afs.collection('users').doc(this.auth.getUserId()).collection('months', ref => {
      return ref.where('endTimestamp', '>=', moment().unix()).limit(1);
    });
```

EDIT 3: So I moved checking out of the snapshot and into another check but it is still creating 2 documents. What you see below is above the other code.

```
this.afs.collection('users').doc(this.auth.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid).collection('months').ref.where('endTimestamp', '>=', moment().unix()).get().then((result) => {
      if (result.empty || result.size <= 0) {
        this.createNewMonth();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail **exactly** what you're doing that triggers this code, what you expect the result to be from that action, and what is actually happening that is not what you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson I typed the extra detail above!

Answer (score 0):

It is expected that your snapshot listener is triggering twice.

The first time will give you the initial contents of the collection.  Then, in your createNewMonth() function, you're adding a new document to the same collection.  The snapshot listener will then trigger a second time when the updated contents of the collection, which now contains the document you just added.

You should know that there is no `length` property on the `snapshot` that your listener function receives.  This is not valid code:

```
if (snapshot.length <= 0) {
  this.createNewMonth();
}
```

`snapshot` is a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) object. If you want to know how many documents are in that snapshot, use its [`size`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#size) property, or its [`empty`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#empty) property.

Also, if you don't want continually monitor the collection for changes like this, consider using [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get) on the collection references instead of adding a listener like you are now.  It will give you a single set of results a single time.

Comment: So it says the snapshot is a `DocumentChangeAction` and `size`/`empty` do not exist. `length` does though

Comment: Whatever Angular does with their APIs doesn't change the fact that your listener is expected to get called twice, one with the initial results, and again when you change the collection.

Comment: okay so I have made some changes but it is still producing 2 documents could you please take a look